# Plotting Eigenvalues and severe Noise Problems

Tags: plotting, eigenvalues

I am trying to plot Eigen values of my System Hamiltonian in Mathematica. This is generating very noisy plot.
This is my code.

```
ϵ = 0;
A[α_, c_, b_, q_] := ϵ + 
2*Cos[k2*b + 2*π*α]*Exp[-π 1/(2*q)]*
LaguerreL[c, 0, (π*1/q)]
B[a_, q_] := Exp[I*k1*q*a]
B1[a_, q_] := Exp[-I*k1*q*a]
b[α_, q_] := 
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A[α, 0, 1, q], 
Band[{1, 2}] -> B[1, q], Band[{2, 1}] -> B1[1, q], 
Band[{1, q}] -> B1[1, q], Band[{q, 1}] -> B[1, q]}, {q, q}];
Plot3D[Eigenvalues[b[1, 3]][[2]], {k1, -3, 3}, {k2, -π, π}]
```

[image]

This is not even correct. Since this is mixing different eigen values solutions.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could experiment with `MaxRecursion` to smooth the plot.  For example, `Plot3D[Eigenvalues[b[1, 3]][[2]], {k1, -3, 3}, {k2, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 6]`.  You could also increase the number of `PlotPoints`.

Comment: @Tim Laska, It takes for ever for 10 recurssion and for 6 recurssion it takes a lot of time and still useless result. Its mixing eigenvalues. Mathematica is almost completely inefficient in calculating eigen values. I have always found these type of problems in mathematica.

Comment: @HazoorImran have you tried using `Eigensystem`? I find it is much more convenient. How large are your matrices? I calculate 1000x1000 and larger often in seconds or less.

Comment: @CATrevillian No use of Eigensystem as well. You can try yourself. The code is up there. Its only 3 by 3 matrix. But its not working. If I increase the dimension of the matrix then you one can guess what will happen.

Comment: @HazoorImran can you clarify what you are looking for in the way of a result? I get a very clear plot using a combination of `Eigensystem`, `N`, `Sort`, and `PlotPoints -> 50`. I also made the functions include k1, k2, and \[Epsilon].

Comment: @CATrevillian I used all of them but thenever it gives me a torn stripe plots. I did this with 100 points as well. But its better than what i was getting before. However still not acceptable.

Comment: There is no reason to expect the second eigenvalues will change continuously as a function of the parameters. In fact there is sound reason to expect they will not do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So my first step was to redefine your functions as such:

```
ClearAll[A,ε,B,B1,b];

A[α_, c_, b_, q_, ε_][k2_]:=ε + Cos[k2*b + 2*Pi*α]*Exp[-Pi 1/(2*q)]*LaguerreL[c, 0, (Pi*1/q)];

B[a_, q_][k1_]:=Exp[I*k1*q*a];

B1[a_, q_][k1_]:=Exp[-I*k1*q*a];

b[α_, q_][k1_,k2_] :=
SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> A[α, 0, 1, q, 0][k2],
Band[{1, 2}] -> B[1, q][k1], Band[{2, 1}] -> B1[1, q][k1],
Band[{1, q}] -> B1[1, q][k1], Band[{q, 1}] -> B[1, q][k1]}, {q, q}];
```

Then I could plot using the following:

```
Plot3D[Sort[Eigensystem[N[b[1,3][k1,k2]]][[1]]][[2]],{k1,-3,3},{k2,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->50]
```

Which gives:

[image: Plot3D produced by above code.]

Similarly,

```
Plot3D[Sort[Eigenvalues[N[b[1,3][k1,k2]]]][[2]],{k1,-3,3},{k2,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->50]
```

And

```
Plot3D[Sort[Eigenvalues[b[1,3][k1,k2]]][[2]],{k1,-3,3},{k2,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->50]
```

Both give the same output due to their use of `Sort`.

However,

```
Plot3D[Eigensystem[N[b[1,3][k1,k2]]][[1]][[2]],{k1,-3,3},{k2,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->50]
```

Gives the disconnected & severely noisy plot

[image: Noisy Plot3D of the above code that does not use Sort.]

And this is due to the lack of use of `Sort`. We can also see this same output with:

```
Plot3D[Eigenvalues[N[b[1,3][k1,k2]]][[2]],{k1,-3,3},{k2,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->50]
```

And

```
Plot3D[Eigenvalues[b[1,3][k1,k2]][[2]],{k1,-3,3},{k2,-Pi,Pi},PlotPoints->50]
```

Which both produce the same noisy & mixed eigenvalue plot seen previously.

If this is not what you are looking for, please, let me know? I hope this helps!

---

***After realizing an error in translating OP’s initial codeblock, the following no longer applies:***

You might also speed up your matrix assembly by observing that your setting of `ε = 0` makes the diagonal go to 0, which could prevent the need to do such extraneous computations when assembling runs of your matrices.

---

Tl;dr: Using `Sort` is key to helping eliminate the noise that was present.